# How to include XML in a CDATA

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I need to include a full XML document inside a text field in other XML document

For example

```
<mytexttag>
   <![CDATA[    
      here the xml document starting with <?xml version="1.0"
   ]]>     
</mytexttag>
```

I must use a fixed XSD and I can not adapt it.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) that CDATA  is still part of the document and it means that the data in between these strings includes data that could be interpreted as XML markup, but should not be.

But i don't know if I can bypass the restrictions. Currently, if I include a complete XML, I have parsing errors

This could be a real example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mytexttag>
    <![CDATA[ <n1:ClientInvoiceExtension xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n1="http://www.myclient.es/facturae/ClientInvoiceExtension/v1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myclient.es/facturae/ClientInvoiceExtension/v1.0/ClientInvoiceExtension_v1_0.xsd"><Version>1.0</Version><LineExtension><InvoiceFamily>ejempló con carañññ</InvoiceFamily><ContractCode>el code</ContractCode><PurchaseRequestCode>String</PurchaseRequestCode><DerivationCode>String</DerivationCode>ContractFileCode>String</ContractFileCode><Patient><IPF>PASAPORTE</IPF><PatientId>String</PatientId><FullName>String</FullName></Patient><Process><Contingency>String</Contingency><Year>0</Year><Province>String</Province><Number>String</Number></Process><MazCenterId>String</MazCenterId><MazCenterProvince>String</MazCenterProvince><Diagnostic>String</Diagnostic><Medical>String</Medical><RecipeNumber>String</RecipeNumber><MazEmployeeFullName>String</MazEmployeeFullName>       <HealthcareDeliveryCode>String</HealthcareDeliveryCode> </LineExtension></n1:MazInvoiceExtension>]]>     
</mytexttag>
```

When a insert special characters like 'á ó ñ' my xml editor says it is invalid xml

I can consider encode in base64, but I have a size restriction in that field and would rather not increase the size

Comment: Does the XML you intend to include in CDATA also has CDATA nodes?

Comment: No, it does not have

Comment: Can you post the specific error the parser spits out if you can't post the entire xml inclusion?

Comment: thanks for the interest. Included a real example (reduced)

Comment: Your example is perfectly valid. Maybe your editor uses wrong character encoding?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! I will now test with my programming language

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your XML has characters not encoded in UTF-8 format...